# Location of spark-defaults.conf when using sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, playframework

Where can i find spark-defaults.conf file when i import spark from sbt has jars. 
I use play framework/web service that uses spark and i need to add a configuration to spark-defaults.conf in order to be able to connect to neo4j.
How can i define that kind of configuration or is there a way to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving an answer just in case someone may use it in the future.
When defining your sparkSession, use the method .config for defining any configuration needed that you would normally put into spark-defaults.conf, so in this case I used :

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .config("spark.neo4j.bolt.password", "mypassowrd")
  .getOrCreate()
```